# BadMethodCallException in compiled.php line 6341: Method after does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, staging

I am trying to deploy my site to a staging domain. I have done everything correctly(as far as I know) but I get this error when i go to my domain from the browser.

> > BadMethodCallException in compiled.php line 6341:
>
> Method after does not exist.
>
> in compiled.php line 6341 at Router->__call('after',
>   array(object(AfterFilter))) in compiled.php line 2265 at
>   Router->after(object(AfterFilter)) in compiled.php line 2265 at
>   Application->boot() in compiled.php line 2265 at
>   BootProviders->bootstrap(object(Application)) in compiled.php line
>   1693 at
>   Application->bootstrapWith(array('Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\DetectEnvironment',
>   'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration',
>   'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging',
>   'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions',
>   'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades',
>   'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders',
>   'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders')) in compiled.php line
>   2465 at Kernel->bootstrap() in compiled.php line 2415 at
>   Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in compiled.php line
>   2400 at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54

This is my .env file

```
APP_ENV=staging
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=key

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

In my local environment it works fine so its probably not an issue with my code. Are there some configuration settings am missing? I have deployed sites before with the same method and I have never encountered this issue. The only difference is that this site uses domain routing.

Comment: Not much to say withtout the actual code. But apparently the method `after` is not defined.

Comment: the method after is not in my code, I am guessing it has something to do with the environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was newrelic agent. So I uninstalled it from my staging server. This is a temporary solution as I need the agent in production. More on this: [Laracasts Forum](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/badmethodcallexception-with-message-method-after-does-not-exist)